# Partition has less shrink space than expected

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning

I have a dual-boot OS setup with Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

In the picture below, (C:) 376.14 GB is Windows 7, and Recovery (D:) is 21.87 GB is its recovery partition.  I'm not sure what SYSTEM 300 MB is, but I'm pretty sure it has to do with Windows 7.  The 37.65 GB is Ubuntu, and I believe the 11.17 GB is its swap space.  Everything is on a 480GB SSD.

I'm trying to shrink the Windows partition and extend the Ubuntu partition.  From the picture, (C:) has 121 GB free space, but when I tried to shrink it on Window 7's Disk Management application, it listed only 2777 MB as available shrink space.  I'm puzzled, what's causing this and how do I shrink more memory?

[image]

Edit:

Here is the Application Log for Event 259:

```
A volume shrink analysis was initiated on volume (C:). This event log entry details information about the last unmovable file that could limit the maximum number of reclaimable bytes.

 Diagnostic details:
 - The last unmovable file appears to be: \System Volume Information\{516e2046-e408-11e4-bb03-a0b3cc44f1e6}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}::$DATA
 - The last cluster of the file is: 0x5d57f5b
 - Shrink potential target (LCN address): 0x3fbd621
 - The NTFS file flags are: ---AD
 - Shrink phase: <analysis>

 To find more details about this file please use the "fsutil volume querycluster \\?\Volume{6de8a945-d13d-11e1-bc89-806e6f6e6963} 0x5d57f5b" command.
```

Here is the output of the `fsutil` command from above:

```
C:\Windows\System32>fsutil volume querycluster \\?\Volume{6de8a945-d13d-1
9-806e6f6e6963} 0x5d57f5b
Cluster 0x0000000005d57f5b used by ---AD \System Volume Information\{516e
08-11e4-bb03-a0b3cc44f1e6}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}::$DATA
```

Answer (score 1):

#### I'm not sure what SYSTEM 300 MB is

The system partition contains the hardware-related files and the Boot folder that tell a computer where to look to start Windows.

> By default, Windows 7 creates a separate system partition when it's installed from scratch (as opposed to upgraded from a previous version of Windows) on an unpartitioned hard drive. This partition is 100 MB in size.

Source [What are system partitions and boot partitions?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-are-system-boot-partitions#1TC=windows-7)

---

#### It listed only 2777 MB as available shrink space

> I'm puzzled, what's causing this and how do I shrink more memory?"**

The answer is right there in the image you posted.

> "You cannot shrink a volume beyond the point where any unmovable files
> are located. See the "defrag" event in the Application log for
> detailed information about the operation when it has completed."
>
> "See 'Shrink a Basic Volume' in Disk Management help for more
> information."

---

#### Shrink a Basic Volume

> The shrink operation can be blocked by the presence of certain file types; see Additional considerations for more information.

...

> **Additional considerations**
>
> - When you shrink a partition, certain files (for example, the paging file or the shadow copy storage area) cannot be automatically
>   relocated and you cannot decrease the allocated space beyond the point
>   where the unmovable files are located. If the shrink operation fails,
>   check the Application Log for Event 259, which will identify the
>   unmovable file. If you know the cluster or clusters associated with
>   the file that is preventing the shrink operation, you can also use the
>   fsutil command at a command prompt (type fsutil volume querycluster /?
>   for usage). When you provide the querycluster parameter, the command
>   output will identify the unmovable file that is preventing the shrink
>   operation from succeeding.
> - In some cases, you can relocate the file temporarily. For example, if the unmovable file is the paging file, you can use Control
>   Panel to move it to another disk, shrink the volume, and then move the
>   page file back to the disk.
> - If the number of bad clusters detected by dynamic bad-cluster remapping is too high, you cannot shrink the partition. If this
>   occurs, you should consider moving the data and replacing the disk.
> - Do not use a block-level copy to transfer the data. This will also copy the bad sector table and the new disk will treat the same
>   sectors as bad even though they are normal.
> - You can shrink primary partitions and logical drives on raw partitions (those without a file system) or partitions using the NTFS
>   file system.

Source [Shrink a Basic Volume](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731894.aspx)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.  Please see my edit to the question.  I found the location of the unmovable file, but not sure how to move it to another disk (or preferably USB or just delete it if it's not needed).  I'm still a newbie with this stuff.