# Unable to shrink although there is available space

Tags: windows, partitioning, multi-boot

I'm trying to shrink my C: but I cannot shrink it beyond 2624 MB although my free space is 149.06GB. Might need some help :(

[image]

Comment: You have unmoveable files as it says in the dialog..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Partition has less shrink space than expected](https://superuser.com/questions/903636/partition-has-less-shrink-space-than-expected)

Answer (score 1):

Windows has the bad habit of placing essential Windows files at the end and
the middle of the system disk.
These files are unmovable, probably because Windows addresses
them directly by sector-number. The Windows Disk Management knows not to
move them, but Linux applications will move them in order to resize the disk
in effect breaking Windows, so are to be avoided.

To shrink the Windows partition to the minimum possible,
disable first the page-file, set System Restore to zero and empty the Recycle Bin.
Then defragment the disk so as to move all used sectors to its beginning.
Finally, resize using only Disk Management and from inside a running Windows.

Once the disk has been resized to an acceptable minimum,
return all the settings that you have turned off.

Take good backups, since the smallest error during this operation can
end up with a non-booting disk.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reduce the unmovable files. I have created a powershell script that will do it for you.

```
set-wmiinstance -class win32_computersystem -argument @{AutomaticManagedPagefile="false"}; (get-wmiobject -class win32_pagefilesetting).Delete(); powercfg /h off; disable-computerrestore -drive "C:"; defrag C: /l /d /g /k /h /u /v
```

- Disable the automatically managed pagefile setting and paging file C:\pagefile.sys.
- Disable system restore on drive C:
- Disable hibernation.
- Perform defragmentation on C: (Verbose messages, show progress, slab consolidation, re-trimming, with normal priority).

Also if this is failing, run `chkdsk` to fix disk errors.