# How to partition C drive with a very low space to shrink that is lower than available free space?

Tags: windows, partitioning, ssd

I have an SSD, which has available free space 553 GB, but when trying to shrink the partition the space available to shrink is only 1068 MB:
[image]

Comment: Disable the (page file, hibernation file,ect).  Those are unmovable system files which are created before Windows can be logged into.  You can also use a third-party partition program (of your choice) to acomplish a similar task.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to shrink although there is available space](https://superuser.com/questions/1569615/unable-to-shrink-although-there-is-available-space)

Answer (score 1):

The Shrink dialog explains why that is:

> You cannot shrink a volume beyond the point where any unmovable files are located.
>
> See the "defrag" event in the Application log for detailed formation about the operation when it has completed.
>
> See "Shrink a basic volume" in Disk Management help for more infomation

This means that some files (like Page file and Volume Shadow Copies) cannot be moved by Windows, so it will only allow you to shrink until where that file is on the disk.

To see which file is the one blocking your shrink, you can follow the (unclear...) instructions in the dialog to check the application log:

1. Open the Shrink, and right afterward Open the Windows **Event Viewer** (*eventvwr.msc*)
2. Check under Windows Logs > Application for a line that has *Defrag* as the Source
3. Click on that and in it you should see a file listed as ***The last unmovable file*** which will be the curlpit\

After taking care of that one (for instance by disabling the Page File etc.) you might need to do it again and find more unmovable files until you get your desired shrinkage size available.

---

As an alternative, you can do the shrinking using a 3rd party disk/partition management tool, which will usually allow you do accomplish this by prompting you for a system restart and finishing up the tasks while restarting (before the unmovable files are in use.)

Tools like [**MiniTool Partition Wizard Free**](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) or [**AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard Edition**](https://www.diskpart.com/download-home.html).